# How can I access video frame data without mapping to system memory?

Tags: c++, qt, video, overlay, gpu

I'm using Qt and I can encapsulate the video stream from my Logitech webcam in a `QCamera`, subclass `QVideoAbstractSurface` and from there feed it to a video widget (specifically a `QCameraViewfinder`) without problem.  Afaik the video frames never enter into system memory and that's what I want.  However I further want to manipulate this video (add some overlays).  To do this, for each frame I need to get the handle (`QAbstractVideoBuffer::handle()`) and use this with e.g. the OpenGL API to add my overlays.

```
bool MyVideoSurface::present(const QVideoFrame& frame)
{
    QVariant h = frame.handle();
    // ... Manipulate h using OpenGL 
    // ... Send frame to a video widget
}
```

The problem is that when I do this, `h` is invalid, no matter how I specify the `QVideoSurfaceFormat`.  E.g. earlier at initialization I have

```
QVideoSurfaceFormat qsvf(surfaceSize, pixelFormat, QAbstractVideoBuffer::GLTextureHandle);
mVideoSurface->start(qsvf); // MyVideoSurface instance
```

(Relevant docs [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractvideosurface.html#start) and [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideosurfaceformat.html#QVideoSurfaceFormat-1).)  It doesn't matter what handle type I input, none of them are valid (not surprisingly in some cases).

Is there any way for me to access my webcam video frames without mapping?  I'm happy with solutions that break any specific assumptions I have about which Qt classes are the relevant ones, but there need to be overlays and it needs to be done on the GPU.  Is the ability to access them hardware dependent, i.e. I need to choose a device in advance that will support this?